# Add subcommand in go cobra with multiple parents

Tags: go

I want to have the option of the following cmd invocations in a cli tool I am building in `go` using `cobra`:

```
$ mytool envs apps compare
$ mytool envs vars compare
```

So am creating the commands and performing the bindings as follows:

```golang
    rootCmd.AddCommand(envsCmd)
    envsCmd.AddCommand(appsCmd)
    envsCmd.AddCommand(varsCmd)
    varsCmd.AddCommand(compareCmd)
    appsCmd.AddCommand(compareCmd)
```

However, when checking the parent of the `compare` subcommand, it always turns out to be `apps`

```golang
var compareCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Hidden: false,
    Use:    "compare",
    Short:  "",
    Long: ``,
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        fmt.Println(cmd.Parent().Use)
```

The above always prints `apps` no matter if I invoke

```
$ mytool envs apps compare
```

or

```
$ mytool envs vars compare
```

Should I assume what I want to achieve is not possible at least using `cobra`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands are linked using pointers, so the last one you add becomes the parent command. Try two copies of the same command instead:

```
var baseCompareCmd = cobra.Command{...}
var varCompareCmd = baseCompareCmd
var appsCompareCmd = baseCompareCmd

varsCmd.AddCommand(&varCompareCmd)
appsCmd.AddCommand(&appsCompareCmd)
```

Comment: The `AddCommand` refuses to accept `&varCompareCmd` as argument which makes sense given that the later is a pointer to a pointer to a cmd.Command (and it accepts pointers)

Comment: Needed a minor fix: `var compareAppsCmd = *compareCmd` (so as not to be making copies of the pointers but of the values)

Comment: Note that in my code none of the commands are declared as pointers.